# How to redirect trace to file?

Tags: haskell

The problem I am facing is that I need to somehow redirect the console output of `trace` to a file, because the result is very large.

I know that its in principle a hidden side effect, but I don't want to use the `IO`-Monad for that.

I am using Windows.

Answer (score 5):

Please, please, please just use `IO`.

---

You can, in principle, accomplish this evil deed by using `unsafePerformIO :: IO a -> a` but it is a terrible, terrible sin and you're liable to run in to wackiness.

It's actually how `Debug.Trace` does this--here's the source for `Debug.Trace.trace`:

```
{-# NOINLINE trace #-}
trace :: String -> a -> a
trace string expr = unsafePerformIO $ do
    traceIO string
    return expr
```

Note that the `NOINLINE` pragma is actually important--otherwise GHC might inline your call in multiple places and duplicate the effect that you've hidden from it.

---

You will certainly have less of a headache after, though, if you just use the `IO` monad. If you are only writing things, as I imagine, you could also get away with a `Writer String` and then write the output to the file.

Comment: The OP said the output was going to be large, so I wouldn't use `Writer String`.

Comment: You can use `Producer` from `pipes` if you want [streaming logging](http://www.haskellforall.com/2014/02/streaming-logging.html)

Comment: "Please, please, please just use IO." how about I don't want to rewrite half of my code for a single debugging session?